# addEventListener on all elements works, but sometimes it alert message twice or more times

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want add event listener to any element of the page. For example I want alert any message when I click anything.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(){alert('asd');}, true)
```

And it works, but sometimes it alert message twice or more times. Bubbling is reason? Any idea how to limit that only for one result for one click?

Comment: That fact that event fires multiple times, bubbling or capturing it's not reason of it.

Comment: Yes you are right. Any suggestions ?

Comment: check your source code, maybe you bind event multiple times, or can your provide structure of your html and javascript code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: in fact I am creating a firefox extension, with basic function to get click count. So clicking anything should increment my counter++. No more code there.

Comment: check event listeners in your browser developer tools, there should be list of all event handlers. and check your mouse is it working properly? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

further reading : [Event bubling and capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing/4616720#4616720)

Comment: Nope. Testing on bing.com when clicking radio button below search input

Answer (score 0):

**Check out this:**

```
 document.getElementById("my_id").addEventListener("onclick", function, false);
```

Comment: There is an error in javascript statement. addEventListener return undefined, so channing is not possible, and correct syntax of `addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);` [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: on that above link use same thing like as following   var el = document.getElementById("outside");
el.addEventListener("click", modifyTextsunction, false); it also same for my code.

Answer (score 0):

just use `event.stopPropagation`

Try the below code:

```
 document.addEventListener('click', 
 function(event)   {
 event.stopPropagation();
 alert('asd');
}, 
true);
```